# Installing mysqlclient failed using pyproject.toml and poetry install

Tags: mysql, streamlit, pyproject.toml, toml, libmysqlclient

I have `pyproject.toml` in the root dir of my Streamlit app and I use `poetry install` to create the virtual environment and install dependencies. I am running into a problem installing `mysqlclient` because it throws this error:

```
 • Installing mysqlclient (1.4.6): Failed

ChefBuildError

Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_wheel

/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
```

Here is the pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "Testing"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Testing mysqlclient installation"
authors = ["me <me@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "src"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
mysqlclient = "*"
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't it handle the installation of the `mysqlclient` ?

Comment: I fixed this on macOS by installing mysql `brew install mysql`